# HTACCESS in subfolder disables access to root folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, password-protection

In my site i have separated admin and root folder, so in my localhost/site/ i have

- admin/.htaccess
- index.php

.htaccess requires username and password for admin subfolder, but it asks me for them when i try to access localhost/site, root folder. Help please?

Comment: What file are you trying to include from the `admin` directory on your `index.php` page?

Comment: oh i forgot that i am including a file from upload folder in admin. Is there a chance i can include it?

Comment: Don’t include via HTTP, include via local file system.